# Convert the List<Long> of java bean to the json of mysql in Spring data JPA

Tags: mysql, json, spring-data-jpa, type-conversion

I have tried to use @Convert by spring-data-jpa, but I get an error, this is my code:

```
entity
@Convert(converter = ListExtendConverterJson.class)
private List<Long> receivers;

ListExtendConverterJson implements AttributeConverter<List<Long>, String>:

@Override
public String convertToDatabaseColumn(List<Long> list) {
    String result =  JSONArray.toJSONString(list);
    return result;
}

@Override
public List<Long> convertToEntityAttribute(String s) {
    List<Long> result = JSONArray.parseArray(s, Long.class);
    return result;
}
```

This is the error message:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Long cannot be cast to java.util.List
at com.qf.posp.pub.config.entity.json.ListExtendConverterJson.convertToDatabaseColumn(ListExtendConverterJson.java:23)
at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.converter.AttributeConverterSqlTypeDescriptorAdapter$1.bind(AttributeConverterSqlTypeDescriptorAdapter.java:78)
... 78 common frames omitted
```

So what is wrong?

Comment: Maybe [this](https://vladmihalcea.com/2017/08/08/how-to-store-schema-less-eav-entity-attribute-value-data-using-json-and-hibernate/) post will be useful..

Answer (score 2):

At last, i solved this problem. I change my code like this:

```
entity:
@Convert(converter = ListExtendConverterJson.class)
private Long[] receivers;
```

---

```
public class ListExtendConverterJson implements AttributeConverter<Long[], String> {

@Override
public String convertToDatabaseColumn(Long[] list) {
    String result =  JSONArray.toJSONString(list);
    return result;
}

@Override
public Long[] convertToEntityAttribute(String s) {
    List<Long> list = JSONArray.parseArray(s, Long.class);
    Long[] result = new Long[list == null ? 0 :list.size()];
    if(!CollectionUtils.isEmpty(list)) {
        int i = 0;
        for(Long l : list) {
            result[i] = l;
            i ++;
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Change the List Collection to a Array.By this way, it work normally!